# Django view arguments return the string of the view, not the intended value (for checking wrong password)

Tags: python, django, authentication

Here are my codes.

The views.py.

```
def index(request, wrong_password=False):

    print(wrong_password)

    return render(request,
        "app/index.html", {
            "user": request.user,
            "wrong_password": wrong_password
        }
    )

def login_function(request):
    user = authenticate(
        username=request.POST["username"],
        password=request.POST["password"]
    )

    # For correct and wrong password.
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("app:index"))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(
            "app:index",
            args=(True,)
        ))
```

The urls.py.

```
url(r"^$", views.index, name="index"),
url(r"^(?P<wrong_password>\w+)/$", views.index, name="index"),
```

I expect the `print(wrong_password)` (The 3rd line in `def index(...)`) to return `True` when the password inputted was wrong and return `False` for anything else.

Without these codes,

```
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(
        "app:index",
        args=(True,)
    ))
```

my web application works fine. However, with it, the `login()` function does not work (it does not authenticate then login the user). Additionally, `print(wrong_password)` returns `"login_manager"` instead of `True` or `False.`.

My intention is to make the user aware if the password inputted was wrong. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is not the right approach. You shouldn't redirect after an unsuccessful login; just redisplay the template with the error.

Comment: Alright, my sorry. However, if I use `render()` instead the `HttpResponseRedirect()`  that the URL after the failed login is index/login_function instead of just index. Is this okay?